# How to convert Tensorflow Simple Audio Recognition frozen graph(.pb) to Core ML model?

Tags: python, ios, swift, tensorflow, coreml

I have been trying to implement the [Tensorflow's simple audio recognition](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition) to an iphone app. After some research i found that i need to convert the Tensorflow's frozen graph .pb file to core ML model and then use it in the iOS apps. So i tried following [this](https://hackernoon.com/integrating-tensorflow-model-in-an-ios-app-cecf30b9068d) sample and referenced [this](https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml) convertor. But it looks like the convertor was mainly written to convert models that take image as input.But My model should be able to take audio .wav files as input. `

```
import tfcoreml as tf_converter
tf_converter.convert(tf_model_path = 'my_frozen_graph.pb',
                     mlmodel_path = 'my_model.mlmodel',
                     output_feature_names = ['labels_softmax:0'],
                     class_labels = 'classes.txt'
                     )
```

When i try to convert my graph to core ML model using the above code i get the following error response.

```
(env3) minimaci73$ python model.py
WARNING:root:Keras version 2.2.0 detected. Last version known to be fully compatible of Keras is 2.1.6 .
WARNING:root:TensorFlow version 1.8.0 detected. Last version known to be fully compatible is 1.5.0 .

Loading the TF graph...
Graph Loaded.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/minimaci73/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tfcoreml/_tf_coreml_converter.py", line 204, in _convert_pb_to_mlmodel
    shape_list = shape.as_list()
  File "/Users/minimaci73/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 900, in as_list
    raise ValueError("as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.")
ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 6, in <module>
    class_labels = 'conv_labels.txt'
  File "/Users/minimaci73/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tfcoreml/_tf_coreml_converter.py", line 586, in convert
    custom_conversion_functions=custom_conversion_functions)
  File "/Users/minimaci73/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tfcoreml/_tf_coreml_converter.py", line 206, in _convert_pb_to_mlmodel
    raise ValueError('Please provide the shape for the input {} through the argument \'input_name_shape_dict\''.format(input_name))
ValueError: Please provide the shape for the input wav_data:0 through the argument 'input_name_shape_dict'
(env3) minimaci73$
```

As per the last error message I need to enter the input shape of the `input wav_data:0`. So i created the text summary of the frozen graph as mentioned in the tutorial and looked up on the `wav_data` input shape. But the input shape is `<unknown>` for this.

[image]

I would like to know if there are any other methods to convert this file into core ML model? or Is there any way to use the frozen graph .pb file directly in an ios **swift** app ?

The Tensorflow-experimental Swift framework is also poorly documented. If you guys have any good resource on this, please share.

`Update`
As per the console log i downgraded the `keras` and `tensorflow` versions and also as per Matthijs answer i have added the `input_name_shape_dict = { "import/wav_data:0" : [1, 16, 44100, 1]`  Now the console shows the error in different way

```
(env3) minimaci73$ python model.py

Loading the TF graph...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 7, in <module>
    class_labels = 'conv_labels.txt'
  File "/Users/minimaci73/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tfcoreml/_tf_coreml_converter.py", line 586, in convert
    custom_conversion_functions=custom_conversion_functions)
  File "/Users/minimaci73/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tfcoreml/_tf_coreml_converter.py", line 153, in _convert_pb_to_mlmodel
    tf.import_graph_def(gdef, name='')
  File "/Users/minimaci73/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 316, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/minimaci73/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 541, in import_graph_def
    raise ValueError('No op named %s in defined operations.' % node.op)
ValueError: No op named DecodeWav in defined operations.
(env3) minimaci73$ python model.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply an input shape to the converter:

```
input_name_shape_dict={ "import/wav_data:0" : [1, input_height, input_width, channels] })
```

If your data is 1-dimensional, then the height and width should be 1 and channels should be the length of the data.

You may run into other conversion errors too, but this is the first step. :-) (tfcoreml needs to know the input shape so that it can run the model with some fake data.)

Comment: Hi @Matthijs Hollemans sorry for the delayed response. Thanks for the input structure. I have added your code but still i face the same error message. Also please check the updated question

Comment: That's a different error, You cannot convert this TF graph to Core ML because Core ML doesn't have a "decode wav" operation. You should make a new graph that doesn't have this operation and do the WAV decoding yourself in Swift.

Comment: Thanks for he quick update. Will try and update here.

Comment: Hi @Matthijs Hollemans. The frozen graph that i have trained has to be used in both iOS and Android apps. I would like to know that whether converting it to Tensorflow lite tflite file and then using the c++ apis (.mm) in ios and java in android will work, without me decoding the wav in the mobile native swift and java ?. Are there any other alternatives available ?

Comment: Try it. TF Lite only supports a limited number of operations, so it's possible DecodeWav still doesn't work. But you can provide your own implementation in that case.

Comment: Did you manage to get a working solution to this @kautham? I'm also interested in building a POC of this on IOS

Comment: @fatlog Sorry for the delayed response. There is no exact solution available for this right now. Just like Matthijs Hollemans responded earlier the TF Lite does not support DecodeWav yet. So all we can do is go with traditional method of converting the audio file to Spectrogram image and then re-training a TF Lite convertible image models like Imagenet and Inception.